# Как в Sql Server Managment Studio добавить вкладку debug(Отладка)?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Читаю книгу, и там используют вкладку debug, как представлено на рисунке 1.
Моя версия Sql Server Managment Studio представлена на рисунке 2 и на нем же видно, что у меня нет debug, почему так?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Начиная с SSMS 18+ дебаггера в нем больше нет. Вот ссылка, где это обсуждалось (под нижним ответом есть ссылка на официальный источник): https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/241881/195840

Comment: P.S. Для дебага sql-запросов сейчас используют Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

Последней версией SSMS со встроенным отладчиком является версия 17.9.1. Вы можете установить ее в дополнение к текущей версии SSMS 18. *.

Обе версии SSMS могут сосуществовать на одном компьютере.

[Put Debugger back into SSMS 18](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/35881492-put-debugger-back-into-ssms-18)